# typeahead with dynamic field name in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have created a typeahead,

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Search'" ng-model="selected" typeahead="Customer as Customer.name for Customer in typeaheadSrc | filter:$viewValue" />
```

with below data,

```
$scope.typeaheadSrc = [{
id:1,
name:'data1'
},
{
id:2,
name:'data2'
}];
```

above code works perfectly fine, but i want to pass column name dynamically. In the above code i have given 'Customer.name' , i dont want to hardcode the columnname. I get column name in scope variable, now i want to assign it here. I tried to do as below, but it did not work

```
$scope.columndata = 'id';  

 <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Search'" ng-model="selected" typeahead="Customer as Customer.columndata for Customer in typeaheadSrc | filter:$viewValue" />
```

instead of name field i am assigning columndata, but its not working . Please tell me how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Search'" ng-model="selected" typeahead="Customer as Customer[{{columndata}}] Customer in typeaheadSrc | filter:$viewValue" />
```

Here **columndata** will be scope variable